# Creating AGL for Named Instance on SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, availability-groups

I have installed a Named Instance on an existing server so the set up is like the following:

Server 1:
QA01 - Default Instance
QA01\BU0 - Named Instance

Server 2:
QA02 - Default Instance
QA02\BU0 - Named instance

I already have an AG with replicas from QA01 to QA02.  There is already an AGL created called AGL1 and it's connected to the default instance.

I then created another AG on the Named Instance called with a listener called AGL2, with the replicas from QA01\BU0 to QA02\BU0.

The AGL2 was created successfully but when I connected, it would connect to the Default Instance and not my named instance.

It would only connect to the named instance if I used AGL2\BU0.  Is it possible to create a listener so that I only have to use AGL2 and it will point to the named instance?  Or is that not possible and I must include the \BU0 in order to connect?  I had tried looking it up online and in forums but it's not really clear.

Am I not setting it up correctly?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: I [previously answered this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/319646/how-does-sql-browser-work-when-default-port-is-missing-and-ag-listener-specifies/319655#319655) and you'll need to properly setup the server and network configuration to allow for this.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that I have not done this myself, if I am spending enough money on SQL to have an Availability Group then I don't recommend the inefficiency that comes with Named Instances (not themselves, but the implication that you have multiple instances on the same resources)... SQL makes each compute core expensive.

BUT, it looks like if you make the port for the named instance static (same on all nodes) and then specify the port number when you create the listener, it will work as you want, where you just connect to the listener name, and it will handle mapping to the correct port(s) and you won't need to specify the instance name when connecting.

```
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP [MyAG]
ADD LISTENER 'SQL2' (WITH IP ( '<SQL2_ip_address>' ), PORT = 12345);
```

References: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/create-or-configure-an-availability-group-listener-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16#TsqlProcedure

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/using-availability-groups-with-a-named-instance#post-3987716